# Cannot execute blank app of VS2012 Express or Ultimate in Windows8 Release Preview

Tags: exception, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, xamlparseexception

I create a new C# blank app (XAML) in VS Express 2012 or Ultimate. 
The app compiles but when executing I always get an exception:

Message: XAML parsing failed.
Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush

Does anyone know why that happen?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any xaml in your app?  If so, post it.

Comment: are you running Windows 8 RTM or the Release Preview?

Comment: I'm running the Release Preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Windows 8 RTM and now it works.